# Can $ f\colon \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $ \forall y \in \operatorname{im}(f)$, $f^{-1}(y) = \{a_y,b_y\} $ be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

This is the problem we want to solve:

> Can $f\colon \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $ \forall y \in \operatorname{im}(f)$,   $ f^{-1}(y) = \{a_y,b_y\}, a_y \neq b_y $ be continuous?

Originally I've seen this question on an exam but it was stated only for the case $ k = n = 1 $ and $f$ surjective, which made it really easy to show $f$ can't be continuous, by using the Weierstrass extreme value theorem. A very similar argument seem to work for any $k$, as long as $n=1$. However, for general $k$ and $n$ this seems much harder. I don't see how surjectivity affects this problem, so I've dropped this assumption for now. Edit:Slup commented below, showing the relevance of surjectivity for this question.

Induction on $n$ and looking at projections of $f$ onto individual coordinates seemed tempting at first, but the composition of $f$ with a projection seems to lose any traces of the property that the inverse image of a point = exactly two points, so I don't see how this could be useful.

Trying to visualise this for $k=n=2$, it intuitively seems that in order to transform the space in this way, we would have to 'tear' it along some curve. For bigger $k = n$, that becomes 'tearing' along some $n-1$ dimensional manifold, but that's obviously completely informal, sort of useless and I completely have no idea how this idea could be translated into a formal proof.

Bonus question: Does the answer or the proof change in a significant way if we limit the domain to $ f:\overline{\mathbb{B}^k} \to \mathbb{R}^n $? We operate on a compact ball now, so that's fairly different from $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: Note: it is impossible to get a two-to-one map with a polynomial from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$, since every polynomial equation has a discriminant that must become zero for *some* input value.

Comment: @fermesomme no, they of course depend on y, otherwise the question would be kind of stupid. Good point though, I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Suppose that such continuous map exists. Then it should be a two-fold covering of its image. So your question is about subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ having $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a fundamental group and $\mathbb{R}^k$ as a universal covering. In particular, such a map could not be surjective.

Comment: @slup Thank you for the comment. I'm not familiar with the theorems you're refering to, but I will try to read up on this. However, in general the question is stated without the assumption of surjectivity, so I'm still very much interested in what happens then.

Comment: What may comment reveal is that your question is highly nontrivial. I must say that it would be nice if someone could provide an elementary and complete answer.

Comment: @Slup why can't there be continuous (two-to-one) maps that fail to be covering maps?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. That's why I write "should be" in my comment above!  There might be some highly pathological maps of this kind, which are not covering maps. Note that they must not be closed. That is why I am looking forward for a nice answer.

Comment: A possibly silly question, not directly related to your question: how is surjectivity used in the $n=k=1$ case? It seems you can prove it only using EVT.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi yes, I think I've proven it without using surjectivity.  It's just an assumption that was in that original exam question, but I don't know for what reason.

Comment: Alright, then surjectivity seems to be completely out of the picture.

Comment: Please see here- http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17707/two-to-one-continuous-mapping-from-r%C2%B2-to-r%C2%B2

Answer (score 1):

I did not read the paper of Mioduszewski mentioned in one of the posts. I only
have some partial answers when $f$ is more regular than continuous.

If $k\leq n$ and $f:\overline{B}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (the bonus
question) is Lipschitz continuous, then using the area formula for Lipschitz
functions (it's in the book of Evans and Gariepy "Measure theory and fine
properties of functions")
$$
\infty>L\mathcal{L}^{k}(\overline{B})\geq\int_{\overline{B}}Jf\,dx=\int
_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\mathcal{H}^{0}(\overline{B}\cap f^{-1}(\{y\})\,dy=\int
_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}2\,dy=\infty,
$$
which is a contradiction. Here, $Jf$ is the Jacobian of $f$, $L$ is the bound
of $Jf$, and $\mathcal{H}^{0}$ is the counting measure. If $f:\mathbb{R}%
^{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Lipschitz continuous and $Jf$ has finite
integral, you get the same contradiction.

If $k>n$ and $f\in C^{k+1-n}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$, then using Sard's theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard's_theorem the set of points $\{x\in
\mathbb{R}^{k}:\,Jf(x)=0\}\cap f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is empty for $\mathcal{L}^{n}$
a.e. $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Hence, if $f$ is onto or if $f(\mathbb{R}^{k})$ has
positive measure, then taking $y\in f(\mathbb{R}^{k})$ such that
$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{k}:\,Jf(x)=0\}\cap f^{-1}(\{y\})=\emptyset$, we get that
$Jf(x)$ has rank $n$ and so we can apply the implicit function theorem to
conclude that $f^{-1}(\{y\}$ is locally the graph of a function. In particular
$f^{-1}(\{y\})$ cannot consists of two points.

Answer (score 0):

A negative answer for the case $k>n=1$.

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R^k $ be twin points. Let $c$ and $d $ other points. Take a path from $a $ to $c $ to $d $ to $b $. By the mean value theorem the twin points are extremal on that path. Say they are minima. This remains true even if we change the point $d $ to be any point; therefore $a $and $b $ are global minima. Since this is true for any pair of twins, any such pair are extremal. But this impossible because $ \mathbb R^k$ contains more than 4 points.

The same argument holds for the closed ball.

Comment: Edit: a solution to the bonus problem

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming $f$ is surjective). Let $n=k=2$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^2, a_y=a, b_y=b.$ Consider the line between $a$ and $b$, $r$. This splits $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $2$ connected components, $P_1$ and $P_2$. Since these are connected, if $f$ was continous then their images through $f, Q_1$ and $Q_2$, would be connected as well, and their intersection would be empty. Since $r$ is also connected, its image $s$ is connected as well, and it contains $y$. Furthermore, since $f(a)=f(b)=y, s$ is not injective, in fact it splits $\mathbb{R}^2$ in at least $3$ connected components. Since continous functions can only decrease the number of connected components, we have a contradiction.

For a general case with $k=n$ i think it suffices to take an adequate number of points in order to split the domain and codomain and use a similar reasoning (eg for $k=n=3$ take two points such that their preimages are coplanar and split $\mathbb{R}^3$ using a plane and a weird surface). I also think this reasoning, if a bit modified, works for $k>n$ as well (eg if $k>n=1$, it's even simpler: $\mathbb{R}^k - \{a, b\}$ is connected but its image $\mathbb{R} - \{y\}$ is not, so $f$ is not continous).